# How do I make sure sentences begin with a capital letter Lua

Tags: lua

I'm working on writing an auto-correct software in Lua, and am wondering how to take a string such as "hello what's your name? mine's Tom." and output "Hello what's your name? Mine's Tom.", with capital letters where they are supposed to be. If anyone could help me that would be great, as I'm not the best at Lua.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Ideally, you should provide some code, to help the community help you.

Comment: `s = s:gsub("[!?.]%s", "%0\0"):gsub("%f[%Z]%s*%l", s.upper):gsub("%z", "")`